# Checking if random generated code exists in DB, if so then re-generate

Tags: php, laravel

I am uploading images and saving their name into a db.

I generate their name like so:

```
$uniqueImageID = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 15);
```

Now, my app is small and I can never imagine the two same codes being generated, but thats not the point.

Im looking for how to go about checking for a matching row, and if there is a match then generate a new number and check again. Just cant get my head around it.

My thinking is to create a function with a loop that checks the DB and keeps on going until a match is not found. Then it returns a actual unique code.

A simple function using Laravel is:

```
function checkForRow($image_file_name_temp) {
    $query = DB::table('image_uploads')
                            ->where('image_file_name', $image_file_name_temp)
                            ->first();
    $count = count($query);
    if ($count > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in english terms:

```
while (checkForRow($imagecode) == true) {
    // keep generating code and checking db
}

OTHERWISE

return $uniqueID.
```

Its been a long day, just cant get my head around this one.

Comment: Why not just use unique hashing and do away with your existing method ? is this not just a hash ?

Comment: It doesnt have to be secure, just needs to always be unique. Ill see if Laravel has anything simple already there

Comment: Have a look at `Hash::make()`, even if you provide the same string, it will never duplicate it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I wouldn't say *never*...

Comment: Why generating names of fixed length ? my recomendations multiply the string with `str_repeat` and use an random number instead of 15 like `rand(7, 20)` this will reduce but not end the probability of colision.

Comment: Hashes are not just good for cryptography, you can use their other properties too. So, for MD5 for example, these are: irreversible (as any hash), 32 bytes long (for any input), repeatable (for same input), low probability of collision (or reasonably so), balanced (you are roughly equally likely to get a hash starting with a 1, a 2, a 3, etc.) So, if you need a string which is always unique, use `md5(uniqid());` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The way I usually handle this is by using mysqls `unique` index (I'm sure your db has something like that too) in combination with php exception handling:

```
public function uniqueInsert($data) {
    try {
        DB::table('image_uploads')->insert($data);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //Check if it was a unique key violation
        if ($e->getCode() == '23000') {
            //Regenerate the unique name and rerun the insert
            $data['image_file_name'] = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 15);

            $this->uniqueInsert($data);
        }
        else {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a unique name where the chance that it is already present in the db is very low, running a additional query for each try is not very efficient. I'm successfully using this approach to generate ~100'000 unique barcodes in a split of a second.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this [Hashids](https://github.com/mitchellvanw/hashids), it's simple and very useful